How to read the stderr of a program if it exits with code 134
I have a (buggy) C program that exits with exit code 134 (abort). It behaves like the following:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Some error\n");
    free((void*)1);
}

If I execute it on the command line, I get the following output:
./a.out 
Hello world
Some error
a.out(8435,0x2004a8f40) malloc: *** error for object 0x1: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(8435,0x2004a8f40) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      ./a.out

This works as expected. (The actual C program is more complicated of course).
When I try to execute it from a Java program, I get the output "Hello world" and "Some error", but not the other lines that contain "malloc". Here is the Java program I have:
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        runProcess(new File("a.out").getAbsolutePath());
    }
    
    public static void runProcess(String... command) throws Exception {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
        Thread outThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        outThread.start();
        Thread outThread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        outThread2.start();
        outThread.join();
        outThread2.join();
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit code: " + exitCode);
    }
}

I get:
java Test 
Some error
Hello world
Exit code: 134

How to get the "malloc" lines? Is it even possible, meaning: does the shell somehow generate these lines? If the shell generates these lines, it is possible to do that in Java as well? (I don't mind that "Some error" is printed before "Hello world".)

Try running in zsh (or any Unixy shell) with a.out 1>file1 2>file2 and see if this output goes to either file or still to the terminal; if the latter it is probably using /dev/tty (or CON: on Windows) (because libc bugs can't assume ANY fd's are valid) and Java can't easily intercept it. On Unix you could capture it using a program that creates a 'pseudo-TTY' (PTY) such as expect (or given a suitable server ssh -t [user@]localhost !), or zsh has a zpty module that looks like it can do this, but I use zsh very little and that module not at all.

Thanks a lot! It looks like you are right! The files don't have the "malloc" lines... Feel free to add an answer, I can then add the details there.

for testing: you could use ProcessBuilder.inheritIO() to check if output is being generated
